# What is tri-node restructuring AVL trees?

Tags: tree, avl-tree

I have googled a bit, but not found much and not sure where to begin.

Say you have a simple **AVL** tree:

```
     2
    / \
   1   3
```

You want to delete a node and then you have to restore AVL property. When one refers to how much tri-node restructuring is caused after deleting a value, what do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, if an AVL tree is updated, in some cases different rebalancing operations have to be performed to maintain the tree's invaraiant, namely being a search tree and being balanced (having a height that is logarithmically bounded by the number of nodes). Up to three nodes have to be taken into account for deciding which rebalancing operation is necessary. The rotation operations are described in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree). The example you have prodided in your question might be too small to cause the necessity of such an operation.